# Sybase equivalent of Oracle TO_CHAR(datetime)

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase, database-migration, date-formatting

I changed my DB oracle -> sybase

So I should have to change my query.
But I don't know  How to I convert my query

Furthermore I have to this query in both (oracle andn sybase => I can't use convert method )

my query is:

```
select ... 
TO_CHAR(Reg_Date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') Reg_Date....
from ...
where ...
```

Please help.

Comment: "I have to this query in both (oracle n sybase => I can't use convert method )". Oracle and Sybase are different products - there is no common way to do what you want, so you will need separate queries for each database: to_char(...) in Oracle, and convert(...) in Sybase.

Comment: As I know  if i use 'cast' instead of 'convert' that query be operated well        is it wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot just cast a string to a date because the date format needs to be known. ('03/01/2017' could mean 2017-03-01 or 2017-01-03 depending on your locale settings.) There is no database-agnostic way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: ANSI SQL date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD', but Oracle default is 'DD-MON-YYYY'. So in order for you to have the same SQL syntax, you will need to set session default format in Oracle via the alter session set nls_date_format=YYYY-MM-DD either in the beginning of the session or on the session connect trigger. Then your SQL will be square across platforms as "select datecol from table_name";

Comment: If you want a SQL that works the same in all DBMS, do not format the date in the SQL query - do it in your application.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 different database products under the 'Sybase' name ... Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE), SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage.  You should provide the name of the database product; it also wouldn't hurt to provide the version, too.

---

Assuming you're working with ASE, you can use  **convert(to_datatype,value,date_format)** to provide the desired output, eg:

```
select getdate(),convert(varchar,getdate(),121)
go
 -------------------  -------------------
 Jun 11 2017  8:02PM  2017/06/11 20:02:38
```

I'm not aware of a single query that would work in both Sybase (ASE) and Oracle.